# Как подключить и использовать шрифт otf

Tags: java, шрифты, otf

Не могу подключить шрифт

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FontFormatException {
        Font font = Font.createFont(Font.PLAIN, new File("444434.otf"));
    }
}
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Can't read 444434.otf
    at java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:1054)
    at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того что бы загрузить и подключить шрифт формата otf нужно. 
Получить получить путь к файлу. У меня не получилось загрузить шрифты из папки resources поэтому подгружаю из той же директории где располагается класс Main.
После читаем файл в поток.
У указываем шрифт классу Font.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FontFormatException {
        // получаем путь к файлу
        URL resource = Main.class.getResource("444434.otf");
        // чтение файла
        InputStream myStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(resource.getFile()));
        // установка шрифта
        Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, myStream);
    }
}
```